# is there a way to set battery save automatically at night?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery

I would like to enable the battery saving mode at certain time and disable it at another time every day, is this possible?

Comment: Is the device rooted? Which Android device and ROM are you using?

Comment: Moto G first gen with Lollipop without root